# Local Folder/File Path related to 'Personal Information'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I'm reading the 'Google Chrome Web Store Developer Agreement' document, and it says:

*"If the users provide you with, or your Product accesses or uses, user names, passwords, or other login information or personal information, you must make the users aware that the information will be available to your Product, and you must provide legally adequate privacy notice and protection for those users."*

**LSS:** I've created an extension which requires the user to type in a local folder path to get access to a local file. The local file path is then saved using 'chrome.storage', and retrieved when the user re-opens the extension

But would you consider the local folder/file paths as 'personal information'? Just making sure...

Comment: You don't get that information, do you?
If so, no problem.

Comment: @Norio Yamamoto Nope, I don't, but the local file path is then saved using 'chrome.storage' if that accounts to anything (edited my answer to include that)

Comment: It doesn't qualify as login/personal information.